# Xcode 8 hangs on startup; [MT] DVTAssertions Warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, xcode8

I needed to work on my app in a different orientation, so I opened my main storyboard and selected the appropriate size class. Xcode froze up, and from that moment forward, I haven't been able to do anything in my project at all. Xcode hangs whenever it opens because it tries to open the storyboard. I checked the console to see what was happening and this message is repeated:

> [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-11224.1/DVTKit/LayoutViews/DVTLayoutView_ML.m:401
>   Details:  An instance of IBUIViewControllerEditorView observed 5
>   non-integral frame changes in a row for an instance of IBUIView with
>   superview IBUIViewControllerEditorView. Further automatic layout
>   invalidation has been canceled. Object:
>    Method:
>   -_invalidateLayoutIfNeededAfterRegisteringRectChange:forView:table: Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
>
> Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: I am having the same issue and its super frustrating. XCode 8 hangs on startup, uses 100% CPU, and I get the same error in the Console.app. I went back a few commits before I upgraded to when I was using a beta XCode and everything works fine. When I first startup like this I am asked to choose a screen size for my storyboard and after I can fully use storyboard normally. However, the next time I open XCode it hangs again. Please let us know if you find any solution.

Comment: same here. This is really annoying.

Comment: @JakeRunzer I haven't given up on this thread. I'm still waiting on an answer from Apple Bug Report and I'll be sure to report back when/if I get one.

Comment: @KevinForté I actually found the cause just now. I have a view that has a non-integral width (e.g. 375.5). The value was calculated by a multiplier of 0.9 on an equal width constraint so I didn't realise it. After I manually change it to 376 (an integral value) then Xcode runs normally again.

Comment: @J.Wang You may have just become my hero. However, what if that non-integral width is necessary and can't really be replaced by a static value?

Comment: @KevinForté Yeah, I agree this should still be a bug. But to make Xcode work I have to do this workaround... I know this sucks...

Comment: @J.Wang Unfortunately, I can't test right now on my end, but I will give it a shot tomorrow and let you know if that solves it. If so, I'll be updating my bug report and hopefully the more precise information will help them.

Comment: @KevinForté Looking forward to your reply. Good luck bro!

Comment: @J.Wang Oy, so I can't even get Xcode to cooperate enough to test this out. I have way too many constraints that are reliant on fractional multipliers to go through and change them all to static values at the pace Xcode is running. I guess I just have to wait on a bug fix? Hopefully this starts getting noticed.

Comment: @KevinForté Hmm, you can try to edit the storyboard file using external editor though. But it's also pain in the ass. Another way is to open the storyboard file in another version of Xcode or on another computer that has a fresh installed Xcode.

Comment: @J.Wang Ah! It looks like the issue only happens when the storyboard is set to iPhone 6S portrait mode? This is extremely confusing and there is obviously something going on, but that does help...

Comment: I'm having this same issue. The error is being spammed to the console, at many hundreds of times per second, leading to 100% CPU usage, and an effective lock-down of Xcode (and a severe degradation of the system performance.)  In my case, I have confirmed that it's ANY TableViewController (custom or otherwise) which is connected in a Storyboard to  UINavigationController as the rootViewController. If I delete the connection, the problem suddenly disappears. Incredibly frustrating.

Comment: Further... I reinstalled Version 8.0 (8A218a), same thing happens. The TableView's AutoLayout is not the issue. (The bug also happens with a newly-dragged-in TableViewController.) For now, I have removed the connections, and will add them manually in code.

Comment: @Womble Ahh, strange. Did entering the transition manually in code solve the problem for you?

Comment: @KevinForté, yes. When I add the connection in IB, it is usually OK until the Storyboard is reloaded (i.e. Xcode restart, or switch tabs). Once reloaded, things go haywire. I suspect that the issue is related to the reconstruction of the XML and the subsequent layout. i.e. Interface Builder is incorrectly building the Storyboard.  When I delete the connection, the incessant logging stops. So, that's what I did. So now I get the Storyboard in code, instantiate the destination View Controller, and then push the dest VC on to the nav controller.  Ah, isn't iOS development wonderful... :p

Comment: @Womble So I just now had time to test this out, and you're totally right, that is the issue. What a pain in the ass; I hope they fix it soon. For now I guess I'll be googling how to set that relationship programatically...

Answer (score 0):

I had some what similar problem
Try this 
Spotlight-> activity monitor-> look for com.apple.CoreSimulator 
Force kill this process 
Then open simulator

Comment: Hm, no dice unfortuantely. It isn't the simulator that's hanging, it's all of Xcode. I can't do anything with it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, what worked for me was to open Xcode in a different project(or new project) and switch off the Xcode Source Control. Go to Xcode preferences, then Source Control, and then untick 'Enable Source Control'. Then if necessary try restarting Xcode and possibly your computer.